# from values.yaml to the deployment with spaces

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to add the following line from values.yaml to the deployment with spaces. But I couldn't.

in values.yaml

```
affinityNode: |
      affinity:
        nodeAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            nodeSelectorTerms:
            - matchExpressions:
              - key: nodepool
                operator: In
                values:
                - loadbalancer-pool
```

in deployment.yaml

```
{{- toYaml .Values.affinityNode }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use normal yaml key pairs instead of a multiline string in your values file:

values.yaml

```yaml
affinityNode:
  affinity:
    nodeAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
        nodeSelectorTerms:
        - matchExpressions:
          - key: nodepool
            operator: In
            values:
            - loadbalancer-pool
```

deployment.yaml

```yaml
{{- with .Values.affinityNode }}
{{ toYaml . | nindent 8 }} # <- use nindent to fix indentation
{{- end }}
```

---

But if you want to keep things as is just add a `fromYaml` statement:

```yaml
{{- fromYaml .Values.affinityNode | toYaml }}
```